# Magento 1.9 - Categories & Products Categories Areas Stuck on Loading

Tags: magento, categories

I'm getting this issue with categories in Magento 1.9, Issues basically to do with Categories page and product > categories.

My site is not new and it has suddenly happened, the only recent events are style changes and few template changes to product gallery (media.phtml).

Im stuck on categories loading... I even left it over night.

**image screenshot**
[image]

It's a nightmare.

I have no console errors except for GET https://www.SITENAME.com/skin/adminhtml/base/default/fonts/fontawesome/font-awesome.css net::ERR_ABORTED which being fontawesome I feel is not related to this.

Has anyone else had this and found a solution?

One suggestion I found was to change mod security in cpanel. I can't change mod security as my cpanel/whm doesn't have that option, possibly as this issues was 4 years ago.

Please save me!?

Comment: check server's error log, magento's exception log.

Comment: check in browser console for error in ajax call

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Below are some fixes that help you to resolve the issue:

1. Try a different browser.
2. Disable mod_security and add whitelist: Check your mod_security audit log and if you see entries from the admin backend, have your host investigate and temporarily disable the module. If your issues goes away, ask your host to whitelist your admin backend.
3. Check your www vs. no www redirects: Make sure you’re only using one form of redirection, either in cPanel, Magento, or .htaccess.